# Symfony Doctrine does not hydrate the whole chain

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I simplified my 3 entities as much as possible below, it shows a simple relationship of `Currency <- 1:1 -> Balance <- 1:N -> BalanceLog`

Entity/Currency.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CurrencyRepository::class)
 */
class Currency
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=3)
     */
    private ?string $code;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Balance", mappedBy="currency")
     **/
    private ?Balance $balance;

    // ...
}
```

Entity/Balance.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=BalanceRepository::class)
 */
class Balance
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Currency", inversedBy="balance")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="currency", referencedColumnName="code", nullable=false)
     **/
    private ?Currency $currency;
    
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\BalanceLog", mappedBy="balance")
     */
    private Collection $balance_logs;

    // ...
}
```

Entity/BalanceLog.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=BalanceLogRepository::class)
 */
class BalanceLog
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private ?int $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Balance", inversedBy="balance_logs")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="balance_currency", referencedColumnName="currency")
     **/
    private ?Balance $balance;

    // ...

}
```

The issue happens when I call:

```
$balanceLog = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('App:BalanceLog')->findAll();
```

This hydrates the `BalanceLog::$balance` to the proper instance of `Balance` type, but it does not hydrate the `BalanceLog::$balance->currency` to `Currency` instance. Instead it wants to use `string` only

Resulting in error:

> Typed property App\Entity\Balance::$currency must be an instance of App\Entity\Currency or null, string used

The dirty fix is to make Balance::$currency without fixed type of `?Currency`. Then it will accept string and the code "works". But it is not correct. The `Balance::$currency` should be of `Currency` type, not sometimes string, sometimes currency.

I tried to make my own method in `BalanceLogRepository`, and for whatever reason this works just fine:

```
public function findByBalance(Balance $balance) : iterable
{

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('bl');

    $query->andWhere('bl.balance = :balance')
        ->setParameter('balance', $balance);

    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

So I am even more perplexed as to why the default `findAll` or `findBy` does not do recursive hydration

After further investigation I found a very weird behavior:

if I prepend this code:

```
$balance = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('App:Balance')->find('USD');
```

in front of

```
$balanceLog = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('App:BalanceLog')->findAll();
```

in my controller, then *the error is gone*. Its as if the `App:Balance` ORM schema of `Balance` with dependencies were not properly loaded until I try to fetch the `Balance` object directly apriori.

Comment: Kind of hard to follow.  Are you saying that $balance->getCurrency() is sometimes trying to return a string?  Or are you perhaps trying to serialize things in which case lazy loading might be the culprit.

Comment: no, I am saying that findAll() on BalanceLogRepository does not populate BalanceLog->balance->currency as a Currency object, but rather as a string. If I fetch Balance object in any way (e.g. from BalanceRepository) before I do BalanceLogRepository->findAll(), then it populates BalanceLog->balance->currency as a Currency object, not string

Comment: Why are you trying to use currency as a unique id for a balance?  Doctrine does not support objects as id's.  At least not without some adjusting.

Comment: Because my app will have like 10 currencies. There is no point in using int IDs. USD is USD, not currency n.1. every currency will have its balance, however it makes no logical sense to merge these tables and put balance columns into currency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some debugging and it looks that `BalanceLog` does not create a full `Balance` Entity instance, but instead a Proxy. The solution was to add eager loading to the `BalanceLog` class

```
class BalanceLog
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private ?int $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Balance", inversedBy="balance_logs", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="balance_currency", referencedColumnName="currency")
     **/
    private ?Balance $balance;

    // ...

}
```

The [UnitOfWork.php](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/b8808099ea7e3dd93f6d038e9c267ae31bcf0f69/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L2855) then does not use Proxy but instead loads the Entity as a whole.

If somebody wonders why querying Balance beforehand made the code work, its because of sophisticated caching mechanism of Doctrine. It saved `Balance` instance for primary key `USD` and then when BalanceLog was populated, it used this instance instead of creating a Proxy.

I still think that Proxy should not enforce strictly typed property from Entity though, but this is something for Doctrine developers to decide.